# execute chmod on boot time on headless debian

Tags: linux, devices, startup, chmod

I am programming a (web based) POS system, dedicated to be running on a debian based ITX-server with apache2 etc.
Currently I am using Lubuntu 14.04 LTS for development (and for the 1st customer) with no login on boot up.
To open the cash drawer programatically independent from a receipt printer, I am using a small chinese :-) USB-to-serial adapter, which I am speaking with using these commands:

```
sudo chmod 777 /dev/ttyUSB0
```

and

```
echo -en '1' > /dev/ttyUSB0
```

which works great, and on the FIRST try. Trial and NO error !

Since I experienced, that it doesn't work anymore after next reboot, until I set the chmod again, I added the local user to sudoers and granted him /bin/chmod with NOPASSWD, and put the chmod command in rc.local

Good so far. Now it works seamless after each boot or reboot.

NOW the question: What I need to do, to get the same result later, when the debian webserver will have no GUI and runs without login ? Whom is to be granted the chmod command, and where should I put the chmod command, if not in rc.local ?

Thanks for answer(s).

Answer (score 1):

I think there are cleaner solutions to your problem: add your user to a `dialout` group or use *udev* to automatically chmod fresh device.

They are discussed here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/112568/how-do-i-allow-a-non-default-user-to-use-serial-device-ttyusb0

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Sergey. There would be different ways to grant anything to a user or group, but... May be that I didn't point out enough, what's my problem: I need to perform a task, which needs root or sudo privilegues, WITHOUT anybody is logged in. Let's say as a service like samba or apache or whatever. Debian runs in a black box without keyboard nor screen.

Comment: Ah, wait moment :-) You said udev... I went into it on ubunti-wiki... this sounds good. Will play around with it. Thanks for now.

Comment: Adding my user to dialout didnt work